# /usr/bin/tidy is called before /usr/local/bin/tidy

Tags: shell, homebrew

I installed a newer version of tidy through homebrew, but somehow still the version within /usr/bin/tidy is called. I haven't noticed any problems with homebrew before and there are no issues `brew doctor`can find. :)

Here is what I get, when I call `echo $PATH` (I removed the ruby related stuff):

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

And that's my /etc/paths

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What output do you get from this command? `file /usr/local/bin/tidy; ls -l /usr/local/bin/tidy`

Comment: the following: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 myUserAccount  admin  32  9 Aug 21:14 /usr/local/bin/tidy -> ../Cellar/tidy/20090325/bin/tidy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you execute the old `tidy`, then installed a new version without restarting the shell?

If so, use `hash -r` to clear the shell's cache so it will go through the path again the next time you try to execute it.

If not, ensure you can execute `/usr/local/bin/tidy`.

Comment: thank you very much. didn't think of this being a possible issue >_<